# Passing instance of Class Module

Tags: vba, excel

Say I create a new instance of a class module. Within that instance block I call another sub which calls the functions in the class module. How can I accomplish this? Currently I can't figure out how it is done. The following is an overview of my code:

```
...
With New FTPClient

    .ServerName = strServer
    .UserName = strUserName
    .Password = strPassword
    .remoteDir = strRemoteFolder
    .TransferType = "BINARY"
    .OpenFTP
    .OpenServer

    Upload()

    .CloseServer
    .CloseFTP

End With
...

Function Upload()

   ...
   .PutFile .remoteDir, currentFile, currentPath, "BINARY"
   ...

End Function
```

(`.PutFile` is a method in `FTPClient`.). Obviously it's having a bit of a fit and doesn't know what `.PutFile` or `.remoteDir` is. Is there some way of passing the instance of `FTPClient` to `Upload`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it if its scoped in the calling code:

```
set client = new FTPClient
with client
   .ServerName = strServer
   ...
   Upload(client)


Function Upload(client as FTPClient)
   with client
      .PutFile .remoteDir, currentFile, currentPath, "BINARY"
```